# What are the semantics in CG programming?

Tags: shader

[msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509647(v=vs.85).aspx)  stated
A semantic is a string attached to a shader input or output that conveys information about the intended use of a parameter

[unity](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-VertexFragmentShaderExamples.html) stated
Semantics is a special clause of Cg to define the default input values of a fragment/vertex Shader

What are the actually semantics? why do we use it? It is necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it tells what kind of data stored in certain field - position, normal, texture coordinates et cetera.

It was useful to describe vertex format in fixed-function pipeline but in programmable pipeline semantics is described by shader, so its definition in vertex format may have no sense (for example, shader may use TEXCOORD0 as normals) yet it still required by compiler.